# Magento: remove <p> tags from the header logo image - "Need file path"

Tags: html, css, file, magento

What I'm attempting to do is to remove some `<p>` tags that wrap the header logo image which does not contain any text because I think they should not be there.

But this is throwing the following error when testing via the W3-validator.

> Line 261, Column 216: Element p not allowed as child of element a in
>   this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

**What file should I look in to locate line 261?**

I'm stuck. I've searched for hours and can't find the file-path to the file that contains the string I need to edit. I currently don't have access to link hints function so that out of the question.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a million
Fish

**Update:** Here is some code regarding the logo from the `header.phtml`

```
<div class="header-wrapper <?php echo $hdr_style?>">
    <header>
        <?php if ( $config['design']['below_logo'] ) : ?>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="grid_12">
                <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('theme_logo', false) ?></a></h1>
                <?php else:?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('theme_logo', false) ?></a>
                <?php endif?>
```

Comment: It'll be talking about line 261 of the HTML, not any of the template files.  The error `Element p not allowed as child of element a in this context.` says it all - it's context dependant so it'd very useful to see the context.  You should post the HTML markup.

Comment: I'm working on this site for a friend and currently do not have access to the magento admin. panel .  All I have is a full site backup.  I need to find the correct file to edit this way if even possible??   I will not have access to Magento admin panel for at least two days. Can this be fixed in the via the admin panel if I get access?  I thought I could simple find the code that contains the p tags and edit that via the complete backup I have the re-upload the file back to the server.

Comment: If you have a full site backup (including database) just deploy the site locally or on a dev server.  The file to change for a logo is likely to be in `app/design/frontend/[your package]/[your theme]/templates/page/html/header.phtml`. But not sure. I was asking for the html to see why the nesting of the `<p>` tag inside the anchor was being thrown as a validation error, that was all.

Comment: Sorry I left this out:  What files from html would you like for me to post?  I'm unsure because there are 100 when viewing the html backup copy I have. Is there a specific file you would like to view.

Comment: I am waiting on the server migration process to complete but would like to locate the error in advance.  I'll just postpone this until the site in on my server.. Thanks for your guidance,,

Comment: You've not posted a link to the site, so we can't look at the source.  I'm not talking about the Magento files, I mean the HTML that you're testing with the validator.

Comment: Hi Mcnab sorry to bother you again but Abhilash offered some advice below I think will help when I gain access to the admin panel . But he left an empty space where a character should be do you have any Idea what character he's referring to, sorry to ask such a basic question.  I was unable to respond to his post, I'm new to stackoverflow please forgive me..

Comment: I don't know.  That's what I have been trying to say.  You haven't posted any of the HTML that generated the error or given us a link to the site.  Nobody here can have a clue what it is, all you've given us is the error, there's nothing to go on that will allow us to help you.  Can you give a link to the live site at least?

Comment: I'm unsure what html file you'd like me to post.. Would the header.phtml help you help me?  This is a link to the website in question.. http://www.icustomlabel.com/

Comment: I hope the code I just posted above might help. If not I'm willing to go back through the code and locate the proper files..

Comment: Yes, that's a big help.  The code comes from `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('theme_logo', false) ?>`.  You need to check the layout files in the theme and see which template the `theme_logo` block is using.  That's where you can find and remove the <p> tags

Comment: Awesome Nick I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Excellent!  We got there.  I'll post that as the answer then.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code comes from `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('theme_logo', false) ?>`.

You need to check the layout files in the theme and see which template the 'theme_logo block' is using. That's where you can find and remove the `<p>` tags.